# How to change span class on dropdown list change event in mvc view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to show datepicker or timepicker based on dropdownlist value in my application.

Below is my code in cshtml file,

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlTime", new List<SelectListItem>
{
    new SelectListItem{ Text="Daily", Value = "1" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="Weekly", Value = "2" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text="Monthly", Value = "3" }
}, "Select a type...", new { @class = "form-control", @onchange = "javascript:ShowCalendar(this.value);" })

<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker9' style="float: right;">
     <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar">
            </span>
        </span>
 </div>
```

Below is my jquery code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker9').hide();
});

function ShowCalendar(id) {
    var datetimepicker = $("#datetimepicker9");
    if (id == 1) {
        datetimepicker.show();
        $('.fa').removeClass('fa').addClass('.glyphicon glyphicon-time');
        $('.text-primary').show();

        $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker9').datetimepicker({
                icons: {
                    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                    date: "fa fa-calendar",
                    up: "fa fa-arrow-up",
                    down: "fa fa-arrow-down"
                },
                format: 'HH:mm'
            });
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

I want to change the span class from fa fa-calendar to glyphicon glyphicon-time but it is not working.

Comment: in addClass remove . in .glyphicon  just use glyphicon

Comment: What isnt working? is the ShowCalendar being called? what exactly is happening? Please provide more information as to what is happening

Comment: Yes, ShowCalendar is being called but the icon on the datetimepicker does not change from calendar to time.